# Blackboard greek mu not embedded in PDF

Tags: blackboard

I'm using the below coding and can see the Blackboard font mu symbol in Yap. When I create PDF the characters are not embedded. Could anyone guide me how to solve this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}

Please check the character ``$\bbmu$'' mu symbol

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no “double struck mu” in Unicode.

Comment: Works fine for me in miktex 2.9.. It used bitmap fonts first but after installation of the bbold-type1 package it uses a type1 font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It pastes a normal mu.

Comment: Worked for me as is: Miktex 2.9 and TexnicCenter.

Comment: Check the logfile.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 1):

There is no “double struck mu” in Unicode; as far as I can tell there are slots for double struck gamma and pi, but nothing else for lowercase Greek letters.

Therefore it's impossible that software can deal with it. All you can get (and do) is a mu.